# Assign a Output into Two Modules in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga, hdl, quartus

In the below Verilog Code, I want to assign my outputs into two modules namely two_input_checker and three_input_checker. But when I assigned them directly as shown as below, it gives a error.

```
module logical_function_check (
  IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4, IN5, IN6, 
  IN8, IN9, IN10, IN11, IN12, IN13,
  OP1, OP2, OP3, OP4, OP5, OP6,
  OP8, OP9, OP10, OP11, OP12, OP13,
  pass1, pass2, pass3, pass4, pass5, pass6,
  fail1, fail2, fail3, fail4, fail5, fail6,
  pass, fail,
  clk
);
  
  input OP1, OP2, OP3, OP4, OP5, OP6, OP8, OP9, OP10, OP11, OP12, OP13;
  output IN1, IN2, IN3, IN4, IN5, IN6, IN8, IN9, IN10, IN11, IN12, IN13;
  output pass1, pass2, pass3, pass4, pass5, pass6, fail1, fail2, fail3, fail4, fail5, fail6;
  output pass, fail;
  input clk;
  

  two_input_checker two_input_checker_inst(
    .A1(IN1),
    .A2(IN4),
     .A3(IN10),
     .A4(IN13),
     .B1(IN2),
     .B2(IN5),
     .B3(IN9),
     .B4(IN12),
    .op1(OP3),
    .op2(OP6),
    .op3(OP8),
    .op4(OP11),
    .pass1(pass1),
    .pass2(pass2),
    .pass3(pass3),
    .pass4(pass4),
    .fail1(fail1),
    .fail2(fail2),
    .fail3(fail3),
    .fail4(fail4),
    .pass(pass),
    .fail(fail),
     .clk(clk),
     .enable(1'b1)
  );
  
  three_input_checker three_input_checker_inst (
    .A1(IN1), 
    .A2(IN3), 
    .A3(IN11), 
    .B1(IN2), 
    .B2(IN4), 
    .B3(IN10),
    .C1(IN13), 
    .C2(IN5), 
    .C3(IN9),
    .op1(OP12), 
    .op2(OP6), 
    .op3(OP8),
    .pass1(pass1), 
    .pass2(pass2), 
     .pass3(pass3),
    .fail1(fail1), 
     .fail2(fail2), 
     .fail3(fail3),
    .pass(pass), 
     .fail(fail),
    .clk(clk),
     .enable(1'b0)
  );
    

endmodule
```

The error is shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5mBk.png)

**How can I fix that error and assign the outputs? Or are there any other method to do that?**

Comment: please provide definitions of your *checker* modules.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have muti driven nets.

Let's take for example your output "`pass1`" - it's driven once from `two_inputs_checker.pass1` output port, and once from `three_inputs_checker.pass1` output port.
What you are trying to do is not allowed in synthesizable HDL.

For what you are doing - a net can have only a single driver.

Same goes for all the nets in the image you gave.
Notice for example, that you don't get this error for `IN3`, which is driven only by `three_input_checker.A2` output port.

What you can do is one of the next, which all depends on what you want to do and what is the behavior you want from your RTL:

***Add more output ports:***

For example, pass1 can be duplicated to `pass1_0` and `pass1_1`, or more cleanly, can be changed to:

```
output [1:0] pass1;
```

Then you can connect `two_inputs_checker` to `pass1[0]` and `three_inputs_checker` to `pass1[1]`.

Obviously, someone needs to do something with two outputs instead of only one output.

***Define some internal boolean logic between the colliding drivers:***

Again, let's take pass 1 as an example.
You can maybe say that it makes sense to define that pass1 should be set only if the two checkers say that they got pass1. i.e.:

```
pass1 = three_inputs_checker.pass1 AND two_inputs_checker.pass1
```

You can specify this logic using RTL coding.
You add internal wires:

```
wire two_inputs_pass1;

wire three_inputs_pass1;
```

You connect `two_inputs_pass1` to `two_inputs_checker`.
You connect `three_inputs_pass1` to `three_inputs_checker`.

then you assign:

```
assign pass1 = two_inputs_pass1 | three_inputs_pass1;
```

***Remove one of the drivers:***

Maybe you don't need all the outputs from the two units.
For example, perhaps it's enough to use just `IN1` that comes from `two_inputs_checker`, so you can leave the `three_inputs_checker.A1` unconnected:

```
three_input_checker three_input_checker_inst (
.A1(),
 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming here that you are assigning one signal to two output ports. You need to use different signals for the two modules' outputs and then OR these signals. Signals cannot be driven from multiple drivers. Example for signal pass1:

```
pass1 = two_input_checker_inst_pass1 | three_input_checker_inst_pass1;
```